# .superfish() and .supersubs() hover intent CP navigation issue

Tags: control-panel, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the Superfish jQuery plugin to add hover intent functionality to the main navigation menu in the EE control panel. Whenever I hover over one of the main menu items like "Design" or "Admin", all of the sub-menus are being displayed rather than just the first child. Has anyone been able to get this to work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="<?php echo URL_THIRD_THEMES ?>md_addon/css/superfish.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL_THIRD_THEMES ?>md_addon/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL_THIRD_THEMES ?>md_addon/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL_THIRD_THEMES ?>md_addon/js/supersubs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul#navigationTabs').supersubs().superfish({
        hoverClass:  'active',
        delay:       1000,                          
        animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},
        speed:       'fast',
        speedOut:    'fast',                         
        autoArrows:  false                          
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: I also have a keen interest in implementing this. The CP menus can get long (eg., numerous channels), and they are unforgiving if you mouse off of them.